# Nginx rewrite rule for Node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm setting up Nginx as a reverse proxy for a Node.JS application.
Node app listens on localhost:3003 and proxy is set up like this:

```
location /otfb {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003;
            #...
}
```

Now the problem is that if I access server like this:

```
http://server.xyz/otfb/someresource
```

then it is passed to Node.JS as

```
http://localhost:3003/otfb/someresource
```

But correct will be

```
http://localhost:3003/someresource
```

Show how to set up rewrite rule so that **otfb** will be removed by Nginx before request is passed to Node.JS

Comment: This post should help you out: http://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that rewrite isn't needed at all
Working configuration:

```
location /otfb/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3003/;
            #...
}
```

Just slashes was missing at the end of URIs